# 301 .htaccess redirection apache server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

So I am having issue I want all requests from

https://transfinmedia.com/author?url=akchopra1-A268

to be 301 redirected on

https://transfinmedia.com/author/akchopra1-A268

but when i use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.*) 
RewriteRule ^author(.*) /author/%1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

requests to

https://transfinmedia.com/author?url=akchopra1-A268 gets redirected on

https://transfinmedia.com/author/akchopra1-A268?url=akchopra1-A268

what am i doing wrong here, completely out of clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ,mod-rewrite appends old `QueryString` to the new target url. To discard QueryString ,you need to put a `?`  (an empty question mark) at the end of the target url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.*) 
RewriteRule ^author(.*) /author/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before using this.

Answer (score 0):

change `RewriteRule` to

```
RewriteRule ^author\?url=(.*)$ /author/%1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6s9lEx/1)